# Is there a way to execute commands on a normal user using shell_exec?

Tags: php, windows, apache, wamp

I am trying to make a script that uses ffmpeg to take a screenshot of a window.
but WAMP is running under localsystem and i cant figure out a way to execute the command under my account

Comment: The issue isn't about the particular user account as it is about the session. Even if you get to launch a program under a particular user account, it would still run in Session 0. Session 0 is a non-interactive user session. Taking a screenshot from a session that doesn't have a graphical UI doesn't read like a meaningful operation.

Comment: the command works under php commandline

Comment: oh i see. how would i get the command to run under a graphical session?

Comment: You are running a service. There is no window. It's wildly unclear what you are trying to do. It's very likely that you do not understand the system you are using, and are making assumptions about it that do not hold. You're going to have to understand how your OS works, and how the WAMP server relates to it.